# What does the prompt "[master +1 ~0 -0 !]>" mean when using Git command line?

Tags: git, version-control

After a few Git commands, I find my command line prompt change from

```
[master]>
```

to

```
[master +1 ~0 -0 !]>
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Is this using git-bash on Windows? Or something else? If “something else” then it completely depends on how your prompt is setup.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall looks like a [Posh Git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git) setup. GitHub for Windows distributes it with their app too.

Comment: Exactly, I am using Posh Git, which is included when I install GitHub windows. Very useful hits to know the current status of my repository.

Comment: @WayneWang those prompts are nice but `git status` is more descriptive and even shows some helpful advices to solve some situations, if you have any doubt on the state of the repo I would recommend you to use `git status`. I also use that kind of prompts (gitprompt on bash and an embed one on fish) but I never stopped to use `git status` to really understand the state of the repo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This represents the number of files:

- added (`+`)
- modified (`~`)
- deleted (`-`)
- conflict (`!`) (from [alisa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2961878/alisa)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27932942/6309))

You can see a [powershell version of that prompt here](http://markembling.info/2009/09/my-ideal-powershell-prompt-with-git-integration).

[image: powershell prompt]

Those represent the status before commit (added means added to the index, or 'staged')

[Here is a more complete version](https://github.com/rvojcik/bash-git-prompt/wiki/Demonstration) of that prompt, which also display the number of commits ahead or behind an [upstream repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309).

[image: commit ahead]

> When you do some changes and commit them, your state is 1 commit ahead of remote. It is very useful to know how many commits you have unpushed.

Comment: Very useful information to know the meanings of that prompt in powershell, Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

And:

- Conflicts ( ! )

Usually there is no conflict, but sometimes it occurs (for example when a file is changed in both your local repository and the online repository, and you want to pull. So Git doesn't know which one to keep).

In these cases, you have to correct and save the conflicting file (that is already marked by Github, showing the conflicting lines) manually.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do have a conflict (!).
Type: git status       -to find out which folder has the conflict.